# Invoking VB.Net Structure Property from C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a VB.Net structure defined like this:-

```
Public Structure MyStructure

    Public Property MyProperty () As String
        Get
            Return "" ' Return something
        End Get
        Set
            ' Do something
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property MyProperty (Byval my_parameter As String) As String
        Get
            Return "" ' Return something
        End Get
        Set
            ' Do something
        End Set
    End Property

End Structure
```

and I am attempting to invoke these properties from some C# code. I am able to invoke the overload with a parameter like this:-

```
MyStructure the_structure = New MyStructure ();
the_structure.set_MyProperty ("Hello", "World");
```

but attempting to use the parameterless version like this:-

```
the_structure.set_MyProperty ("Hello");
```

results in a compilation error:-

```
No overload for method 'set_MyProperty' takes 1 arguments
```

A similar result occurs with the get:-

```
string string1 = the_structure.get_MyProperty("Hello");   // Fine
string string2 = the_structure.get_MyProperty();          // Compilation error
```

Does anyone know how I should invoke the parameterless property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way should work.

```
string string2 = the_structure.MyProperty;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this produces the compilation error: `Cannot convert method group 'get_MyProperty' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?`.

Comment: @BrianHooper I have a working example of your setup without any compilation problems using that line.

Comment: @BrianHooper I see you're using something like `string string2 = the_structure.get_MyProperty;`, but you should use `string string2 = the_structure.MyProperty;`. `get_MyProperty` is a method, `MyProperty` is the property.

Comment: @DominicKexel, ah. I see; I have confused myself. Thanks.